# How can I compare the inputs to some specific data in laravel validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5, registration

I am making an web application and I want only those people knowing a special code can register. How should I do it or check the code entered by the user on the registration form..the validator function in RegisterController has this code:- .

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{ 
     return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'place' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                ]);

}
```

what inclusion should I made.?

Comment: is the code going to be same or each user going to have some unique code stored somewhere say in db??

Comment: code is going to be the same. as of now.

Comment: well in any case you have to extend the validator check this link https://teamtreehouse.com/community/laravel-form-validation-extending-validator

Comment: thank u @RohitS :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this if you are using a controller !!!

```
public function validator(Request $request)
{
    // validation

        $this->validate($request, array( 
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',               
            'body' => 'required'

            ));
```

Comment: @kuru Yes Sir,Kuro, I am new to posting answers !!! Thanks

I tried to put code in a well . but failed

Comment: Happy to help :) !!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to store the registration codes in a separate table, you can do this in your validator.

```
codes
    id - integer
    code - string
```

Validation logic

```
'code' => 'required|exists:codes',
```

If you want to use a custom column name to validate then you can do this

```
'code' => 'required|exists:codes,columnName',
```

---

If the code is a simple hardcoded value then you can write a custom validation rule and use it.

Add this in the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`

```
Validator::extend('registration_code', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return $value === 'supersecretcode';
});
```

Validation logic

```
'code' => 'required|registration_code,
```